# Why isn't my Android app showing up in the app drawer?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I don't know why isn't my app showing on the application drawer.  This is my Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.scrollviewtest1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ScrollViewTest1Activity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:scheme="file" /> 
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" /> 
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />    
            <data android:host="*" /> 

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

I looked at some similar questions on the site, but they don't really apply to my situation.  It does show up on Settings -> Programs however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need these lines:

```
        <data android:scheme="file" /> 
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" /> 
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />    
        <data android:host="*" />
```